# Textbox does not disable when I click the radio button

Tags: javascript

I have this form, I try to add the radio button in the form to disable another text field it but doesn't work, what I try to achieve is whenever I click the radio button it disabled another text field, and when I load the form for the first time both text fields enables even though the radio button is checked.

the HTML:

```
    <tr class="font10black">
        <td>Nama Merchant</td>
        <td>:</td> 
        <td>
        <input onclick="RadioButton()" type="radio" name="type" checked="checked">
        <input type="text" name="txtNamaMerchant" id="merchant" size="50" maxlength="100" onChange="UpperCaseNM()" value="<%=strNamaMerchant%>">
        
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="font10black">
        <td>Nama Pemilik</td>
        <td>:</td> 
        <td>
        <input onclick="RadioButton()" type="radio" name="type">
        <input type="text" name="txtNamaPemilik" id="pemilik" size="50" maxlength="100" onChange="UpperCaseNP()" value="<%=strNamaPemilik%>">
        
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The JavaScript function

```
function RadioButton() {
    if (document.getElementById('merchant').checked) {

        document.getElementById('pemilik').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should place `id="merchant"` in the radio button, not the text field.

Comment: but what I try to achieve is to disable the text field when I select another radio button

Comment: You called `document.getElementById('merchant').checked`, which means you expect "merchant" to be the radio button. But you placed the "merchant" in the text field while the radio button does not have any id. You should match the id of the radio button and the `getElementById`

Comment: Do you want do un-disable input box and un-select radio button when you click other radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an `id` to the `2nd radio button` (eg. "*pemilik-radio*"), then need to check for both condition `checked` and `unchecked` to `disable` the input text fields accordingly.

```js
const merchantRadio = document.getElementById('pemilik-radio');
const pemilikInput = document.getElementById('pemilik');
const merchantInput = document.getElementById('merchant');
pemilikInput.disabled = true;

function RadioButton() {
  if (merchantRadio.checked) {
    merchantInput.disabled = true;
    pemilikInput.disabled = false;
  } else {
    pemilikInput.disabled = true;
    merchantInput.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr class="font10black">
      <td>Nama Merchant</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <input onclick="RadioButton()" type="radio" name="type" checked="checked">
        <input type="text" name="txtNamaMerchant" id="merchant" size="50" maxlength="100" onChange="UpperCaseNM()"
          value="<%=strNamaMerchant%>">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="font10black">
      <td>Nama Pemilik</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <input onclick="RadioButton()" id="pemilik-radio" type="radio" name="type">
        <input type="text" name="txtNamaPemilik" id="pemilik" size="50" maxlength="100" onChange="UpperCaseNP()"
          value="<%=strNamaPemilik%>">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code is disabling the wrong input. Clicking "pemilik" should disable "merchant" and vice-versa :)

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro updated the answer, it'll also handle the case of first time page load.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `id` for both `radio` and `textbox` and in your function enable the corresponding `textbox` and disable the other `textbox`.

Try this one:

```js
   function RadioButton() {
            if (document.getElementById('merchantRadio').checked) {
                document.getElementById('pemilik').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('merchant').disabled = false;

            }

            else if (document.getElementById('pemilikRadio').checked) {
                document.getElementById('merchant').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('pemilik').disabled = false;
            }
        }
```

```html
    <table>
        <tr class="font10black">
            <td>Nama Merchant</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <input onclick="RadioButton()" type="radio" id="merchantRadio" name="type" checked="checked">
                <input type="text" name="txtNamaMerchant" id="merchant" size="50" maxlength="100" onChange="UpperCaseNM()" value="<%=strNamaMerchant%>">

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="font10black">
            <td>Nama Pemilik</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <input onclick="RadioButton()" type="radio" id="pemilikRadio" name="type">
                <input type="text" name="txtNamaPemilik" id="pemilik" size="50" maxlength="100" onChange="UpperCaseNP()" value="<%=strNamaPemilik%>">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: doesn't handle the case when page loads, as per question the `Nama Pemilik` need to be disabled because Merchant radio is checked by default.

Comment: I know but this OP's requirement he mention this behavior in his question

Comment: see the question mentioned as `when I load the form for the first time both text fields enables even though the radio button is checked`.

Comment: Ok when page loaded for first time both text box are enabled. Are you see another behavior in my code?

Comment: yes, both text box are enabled when first time load

Comment: @romli-eko What do you expect when page loads the first time? It must be ignore radio button checked value or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ID for the radio button so that you can check it in your Javascript, like so:

```
<input id="radio_btn_1" onclick="RadioButton()" type="radio" name="type">
```

Edit:

What I am meaning is trying something like this:

```html
<tr class="font10black">
  <td>Nama Merchant</td>
  <td>:</td> 
  <td>
    <input id="radio_btn_1" onclick="RadioButton()" type="radio" name="type" checked="checked">
    <input type="text" name="txtNamaMerchant" id="merchant" size="50" maxlength="100" onChange="UpperCaseNM()" value="<%=strNamaMerchant%>">       
  </td>
</tr> 
<tr class="font10black">
  <td>Nama Pemilik</td>
  <td>:</td> 
  <td>
    <input onclick="RadioButton()" type="radio" name="type">
    <input id="radio_btn_1" type="text" name="txtNamaPemilik" id="pemilik" size="50" maxlength="100" onChange="UpperCaseNP()" value="<%=strNamaPemilik%>">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then JS:

```js
function RadioButton() {
  // If the first radiobutton is checked
  if (document.getElementById('radio_btn_1').checked) {
    // Then get the text field by the id merchant and disable
    document.getElementById('merchant').disabled = true;
  } 
  // If the second radio button is checked
  if (document.getElementById('radio_btn_2').checked) {
    // Then get the text field by the id pemilik and disable
    document.getElementById('pemilik').disabled = true;
  }
}
```

You need to set ID's for the radio buttons and when a specific radio button is clicked (and thus calls your JavaScript function), in JavaScript you have to get to get the text box element by it's ID then disable that.

Comment: but it only disables the radio button, what I try to achieve is to disable the text field when I check another radio button

Comment: See the edit above, you need to check document.getElementById(<radio-buttons-id>).checked then disable the text field by getting the id of the text field you want to disable.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS isn't really checking the radio buttons. It's checking the textfield, because the id="merchant" is attached to the textfield. So in essence your RadioButton() function isn't doing anything, really.

Solution:
(You can also view on codepen: https://codepen.io/jennift/pen/GRmZrep)

First, if you want to disable the second text field, you can do so via js on page load.

I have used the onchange on the radio buttons to pass value so there aren't too many ifs or else ifs in JS to check which radio buttons are checked.

Then, on selecting the respective radio buttons, all fields will be disabled, then turn the selected one back on. Feel free to use a for loop to select all the text fields if you are up for it.

HTML:

```
<tr class="font10black">
    <td>
        Nama Merchant :
    </td>
    <td>
        <input onchange="RadioButton('merchant')" type="radio" name="thetype" checked="checked">
        <input type="text" name="txtNamaMerchant" id="merchant" size="50" maxlength="100" onChange="UpperCaseNM()" value="<%=strNamaMerchant%>a">
    </td>
</tr> 
<br>
<tr class="font10black">
    <td>
        Nama Pemilik :
    </td>
    <td>
        <input onchange="RadioButton('pemilik')" type="radio" name="thetype">
        <input type="text" name="txtNamaPemilik" id="pemilik" size="50" maxlength="100" onChange="UpperCaseNP()" value="<%=strNamaPemilik%>">
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
//disable second text field on load
document.getElementById("pemilik").disabled = true;

function RadioButton(name) {
    //whichever radio button you select
    var x = document.getElementById(name);
    
    //disable all text field
    document.getElementById("merchant").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("pemilik").disabled = true;
    
    //enable the selected field back on
    x.disabled = false;
}
```